# Nuxtjs Axios module, get data at child component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am new to Vue,

I am using NuxtJS and axios module.

I can get the data i need at `pages/index.vue`, but could not get at `components/Stores.vue`

In `pages/index.vue` i do use `async await` and can get the data from the `stores` variable. At the template section i can see the json values using: `{{stores}}`

```
async asyncData ({$axios}) {
      let stores= await $axios.$get('/stores')
      return {stores}
 }
```

In `components/Stores.vue` i try to use `props` but could not get the data, i see nothing using `{{stores}}` at the template section:

```
props:{
      lojas: Object
 }
```

How can i get the stores at components/Stores.vue ?

EDIT :
Just change top vuex now

My code for components/stores.vue where i can not see the json data, for now only at pages/index.vue i can see the data :

```
<template>
{{stores}}
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        async fetch({store}){
            await store.dispatch('lojas/fetchAllStores')
        }, 
        computed :{
            stores(){
                return this.$store.state.stores.all
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, can you clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I need at components/Stores.vue get Json data , i can not see why i could not get it

Comment: Not sure what you mean, are you trying to import the component? Please post a complete code example.

Comment: or , when i have components i can not see how to get data from axios inside that component

Comment: @DanielOrmeño i just add the stores.vue component code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you need some data to be used in several components - it is the use case for [Vuex store](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/).

And do you bind your `components/Stores.vue` `lojas` prop to `pages/index.vue` `stores` ?

In your `pages/index.vue` it should look like

```html
<stores :lohas="stores" />
```

Comment: i just change to vuex, the components/Stores.vue is binded into layouts/index.vue, still do not see the data,

Comment: I figure it out using pages/index.vue and organizing the layout. In Nuxtjs can i have the vuex calls inside components ?

Comment: Yes. In your components, vuex store should be available through ``this.$store``.